# "Ça m'interesse vraiment" or "ça m'interesse beaucoup" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Are both acceptable and normal? I could find examples of both but that approach has led me to awkward phrasing in the past.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You might use them both in numerous contexts and no one would think you were saying anything that differs much whichever you chose.

> (TLFi) c) [Avec valeur intensive] **De la manière la plus profonde**, la plus authentique, au delà des apparences.

- Les élèves sont vraiment intéressés par les travaux pratiques.

**2.** There is however at least one subtle différence  when "vraiment" is better taken au pied de la lettre; the intention is not any more to give added intensity to what the verb communicates but to discard a doubtful impression or answer to a direct question as to whether or not a real interest is  involved; the translation of "vraiment" is then "**really**" or "**genuinely**". Of course, again, in this case, "beaucoup" can be used to the same effect of giving a positive answer that will have a similar consequence, but the use of "vraiment" will be decoded as meaning "really", not specifically "much".

Case 1

- -- It seemed you might want to go half and half on that deal with me, I haven't talked to you about it for some time.
- -- I'm **really** interested, do not mistake my silence about it for a lack of interest.
- -- *Il me semblait que vous seriez d'accord pour faire moitié moitié sur cette affaire, je ne vous en ai pas parlé depuis quelques temps.*
- -- *Je suis **vraiment** intéressé, ne prenez pas mon silence à ce sujet pour un manque d'intérêt.*

Case 2

- -- Can we suppose that this scheme of two monthly consultations could appear ideal to them?
- -- I think they are **really/genuinely** interested in settling for it as soon as possible.
- -- Est-ce que l'on peut croire qu'il trouvent idéal cet arrangement en deux séances de délibérations mensuelles ?
- -- Je crois que ça les intéresse **vraiment** de l'accepter aussitôt que possible.

**3.** When the negative form of this locution is used, a similar interpretation is the best: "not really".

> (TLFi)  Nég. + vraiment. [Signifie que l'on se refuse ou que l'on hésite à affirmer que]

- They pretend to like nature, but it doesn't really  interest them.
- *Ils prétendent aimer la nature mais elle ne les intéresse pas vraiment.*